# git commit not working

Tags: git, github

I am using VS Code 1.25.1 in Win 10 Pro
I recently added Git and it appears to be working with no errors except it does not update git.github.com/jfkirkpatrick/NaTours.  I have no idea where the commits are going!!
Using command in the terminal will do the commits.
I have attached several outputs to start us off.

```
    PS D:\NaTours> git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:jfkirkpatrick/NaTours.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:jfkirkpatrick/NaTours.git (push)

    PS D:\NaTours> git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
credential.helper=manager
user.name=jfkirkpatrick
user.email=jfkirk@ix.netcom.com
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge %f
filter.lfs.required=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:jfkirkpatrick/NaTours.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
PS D:\NaTours>
```

Comment: Once you committed the changes locally, did you push them to the remote?

Comment: @chetanRamparlyaI found the "push" control in the upper right hand corner and click "Push" with the  following error:

Answer (score 0):

Have you pushed your changes? `git push` or `git push -u origin master` if the first time pushing.

Committing does not reflect changes in the remote unless you push.

Comment: I see, I found the push drop down panel in VS Code and executed both push & push to with errors after I entered the public key passphrase.  Reading VS Code and watching videos did not seem to help.  Looks like I will have to go back to the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert @ VS code, but `git commit` on the command line just affects your local repository, which you copied from with `git clone` e.g. github, not the remote repository.  `git push origin <branch name>`, <branch name> being the branch you're working on, e.g. master puts all the changes in your local repository to the remote repository if you have push access, which is permission to write to the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

In the VS Terminal window I entered:

```
PS D:\NaTours> git push
```

fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Comment: PS D:\NaTours> git push -u origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/JohnK/.ssh/id_rsa':
To github.com:jfkirkpatrick/NaTours.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:jfkirkpatrick/NaTours.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you
do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: etc.

Comment: Please add this info to your question, not in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the folder you want to put your repo in
Right-click and select "git bash here" (You need git bash)

Try to do these steps to send all your files up to GitHub:
Copy the clone link from GitHub (remember to add a .readme file when creating repo.)
e.g `git clone {clone-url}`

Make your changes to the repository

CD into the repository
`cd {repository-name-on-gthub}`

next type in:
`git status`
you would get an output that is saying that there are untracked files.

next:
`git add .`

next:
`git commit -m "Your Message"`

next:
`git push origin main`

Now go to the GitHub page:
Your changes should have been added after refreshing the page.